# Converting large number to string in Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, number-formatting

I have seen other related questions, but they did not solve my problem, or may be I somehow missed the exactly same resolved queries.

Here is the problem. The service that I call up returns a JSON response with some keys having large numbers as values, and I want to pass them on to my view and display. The issue is that they are getting rounded off, which I don't want. Actually its coming inside a buffer from which I am doing now:

```
JSON.parse(res.body.toString()) // res.body is a Buffer
```

and sending to view. How can I retain the whole number in the form of a string and send this to view so exactly the same is made available to UI.

I thought may be a replacer will help, but it does not works too.

```
const replacer = (key, value) => {
    if (typeof value === 'number') {
        return JSON.stringify(value);
    }
    return value;
};

//78787878977987787897897897123456786747398
const obj = {
    name: 'John',
    income: 78787878977987787897897897123456786747398,
    car: null
};

var buf = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(obj));
console.log(buf.toString());
// console.log(JSON.stringify(buf.toString()))

// console.log('func res: ', replacer('key', 78787878977987787897897897123456786747398))
// console.log(obj.income.toString())
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, replacer));
```

You can recommend some external trusted library, or better, **suggest me the solution through direct code only**.

**Edit:**

The outcome in short is: Convert the response to `String` before returning from the server. Once it gets into JS (`Buffer` in my case), the conversion already occurred meaning that from the application side, nothing can be done to retrieve it.

Please let me know if there's a real solution to this without modifying server response.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the number is higher than max_safe_integer, so if it *ever* gets parsed as a number, even if it's converted back to a string later (such as with the `reviver` function, the second parameter to `JSON.parse`), it won't be reliable. But luckily, since you have a JSON string, you can `replace` numeric values with string values before `JSON.parse`ing it. For example:

```js
const resBody = '{"foo":"bar", "objs":[{"name":"John", "income": 78787878977987787897897897123456786747398}]}';
const resBodyReplaced = resBody.replace(/: *(\d+)/g, ':"$1"');
console.log(JSON.parse(resBodyReplaced).objs[0].income);
```

Comment: Good way. But can you convert from Buffer and then do it? See my snippet at the ending of question, as I need to start anything from `Buffer` only.

Comment: Just use the `toString()` method you're already using: `const resBodyReplaced = buf.toString().replace( ...`

Comment: Please see if you can find the snippet at https://repl.it/@RajdeepBiswas/LargeNumToString. If yes, then can you modify that a bit. Else this is the content: https://pastebin.com/dUPhLeJd,

Comment: It looks to be empty. `Not sure what to do? Run some examples (start typing to dismiss)`

Comment: Yes, thats the problem with repl I think, but paste the content from pastebin link I added above and run it.

Comment: In the pastebin, the `income` property of `obj` *before* it's been `stringify`ed and turned into a `Buffer` *has already been mangled* due to being higher than `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`.

Comment: Oh. Does it means its already out of the capabilities of JS. I mean, when the actual response was put into Buffer, the rounding happened there itself, even before the node backend received the Buffer response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171816/discussion-between-certainperformance-and-xploreraj).